# MailCore2: determining count of unread messages of a folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, email, mailcore2

Main question is: is there a way to determine count of unread messages of a folder filtered **by extra headers** without fetching all messages?

As we know [mailCore2](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2) provides this api for fetching folder status:

```
MCOIMAPSession *session = ... 
NSString *folder = @"INBOX";
[[session folderStatusOperation:folder] start:^(NSError * _Nullable error, MCOIMAPFolderStatus * _Nullable status) {
    NSLog(@"%d", (int)status.unseenCount);
}];
```

But using above method I can't specify extra headers and in the result will be unread count of all messages.

Instead I can fetch all messages with only headers (i.e. without content):

```
MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindExtraHeaders | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFlags; 
MCOIndexSet *uids = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX)];
MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation *fetchOperation = [session fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder:folder
                                                                                  requestKind:requestKind
                                                                                         uids:uids];

fetchOperation.extraHeaders = @[@"MY-EXTRA-HEADER"]; //<- key part
[fetchOperation start:^(NSError * error, NSArray * fetchedMessages, MCOIndexSet * vanishedMessages) {
    //loop through fetchedMessages array and check for 'flags' property
    int unreadCount = 0
    for (MCOIMAPMessage *message in fetchedMessages) {
        if (!(message.flags & MCOMessageFlagSeen)) {
            unreadCount++;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%d", unreadCount);
}];
```

But this will cost me a lot of time for execution in case if user has a thousands of messages in that folder.

So what is the best solution for this problem?